# How can I count paragraphs in text file using Perl?

Tags: perl, file, paragraphs

I need to create Perl code which allows counting paragraphs in text files. I tried this and doesn't work:

```
open(READFILE, "<$filename")
or die "could not open file \"$filename\":$!";

$paragraphs = 0;

my($c);

while($c = getc(READFILE))
{
if($C ne"\n")
{
$paragraphs++;
}
}

close(READFILE);

print("Paragraphs: $paragraphs\n");
```

Comment: could you add some more info on what doesn't work ?

Comment: 1) `$c` and `$C` are different variables. 2) Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script.

Comment: That seems to count the number of characters that isn't a newline. That's probably not the number of paragraphs. Depending on what a "paragraph" is, you might want to count newlines, or the number of times one newline follows another.
(Plus the fact that there are different variables, as eugene points out...)

Comment: Whoever taught you to use `getc()` in Perl should be shot.

Comment: of course $c and $C are not same-that's my mistake. does not work means that it is not returning the amount of paragraphs which I understand are the blocks of text separated by two newlines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're determining paragraphs by a double-newline ("\n\n") then this will do it:

```
open READFILE, "<$filename"
    or die "cannot open file `$filename' for reading: $!";
my @paragraphs;
{local $/; @paragraphs = split "\n\n", <READFILE>} # slurp-split
my $num_paragraphs = scalar @paragraphs;
__END__
```

Otherwise, just change the "\n\n" in the code to use your own paragraph separator. It may even be a good idea to use the pattern `\n{2,}`, just in case someone went crazy on the enter key.

If you are worried about memory consumption, then you may want to do something like this (sorry for the hard-to-read code):

```
my $num_paragraphs;
{local $/; $num_paragraphs = @{[ <READFILE> =~ /\n\n/g ]} + 1}
```

Although, if you want to keep using your own code, you can change `if($C ne"\n")` to `if($c eq "\n")`.

Comment: eugene y's answer is better for long texts - this one will chew memory

Comment: I feel like I shouldn't be the one to point this out, but I doubt that memory consumption is very high on the list of priorities of the average Perl programmer. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

See [perlfaq5: How can I read in a file by paragraphs?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-a-file-by-paragraphs%3f)

```
local $/ = '';  # enable paragraph mode
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
1 while <$fh>;
my $count = $.;
```

Comment: local $/ = '';
(won't make a difference in a small script but in a bigger script you might upset another modules use of $/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Beginning Perl book at http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/. In particular, the following chapter will help you: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblob.perl.org%2Fbooks%2Fbeginning-perl%2F3145_Chap06.pdf